# Combinatorial argument for $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Can you please give a combinatorial argument for the argument below?

> $$\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$$

From RHS, I drew the following argument: There are $n+1$ people. In how many ways, can we pick $n-1$ people and divide them into $2$ distinct committees say $C_1$ and $C_2$. I cannot get the same argument from LHS. Can you help me?

Comment: Can I suggest a different combinatorial argument?

Comment: Both RHS and LHS are equal to the number of ways of selecting a committee from $n$ people with either one chair or two distinct chairs.

Comment: This is very beautiful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another way of looking at this equation.

Consider the number of ways $P$ of selecting a committee from $n$ candidates with either one chair or two distinct chairs. This can be done in two ways

1) Select the chair(s) first and pick any subset of the remaining candidates.
   $$ P = n2^{n-1}+n(n-1)2^{n-2}=n(n+1)2^{n-2} $$
2) Select a $k$ member team and then choose the chair(s) amongst them.
$$ P = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} \left( k(k-1) + k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^nk^2{n \choose k} $$

(Note: I had already pointed this out in the comments, but thought it would be helpful to write it out as an answer)

Comment: nice explanation Shitikanth........

Comment: For (2) I think it's useful to say the following: (A) Pick a k-member team, (B) for each k-member team, there's k ways to pick a chair and k(k-1) ways to pick the co-chairs, (C) do this for all possible values of k and sum them up :)

Comment: For (1) I think it's useful to say the following: (A) There's n ways to pick a chair, (B) for each of these n choices of chair, the remaining (n-1) people can be either in or out, meaning 2^(n-1) possibilities. (C) There's n(n-1) ways to pick two co-chairs, (D) for each of these n(n-1) choices, the remaining (n-2) people can either be in or out, meaning 2^(n-2) possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

Let $M=(m_{ij})$ be a $n \times n$ matrix of variables.  Then this number counts the number of "rooted" submatrices whose row indices match the column indices.  By "rooted" I mean there is a distinguished element in the submatrix.

*Left hand side*.  Since the row and column indices must match, there are $n \choose k$ submatrices with dimensions $k \times k$, each of which could have exactly $k^2$ roots.  Summing this over $k$ gives $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 {n \choose k}$ as the number of rooted matrices with matching row and column indices.

*Right hand side*.  Now, lets re-do this count, but first choose the root cell $(i,j)$:

- There are $n^2-n$ pairs $(i,j)$ for the root cell such that $i \neq j$.  Once this is chosen, it belongs to $2^{n-2}$ submatrices with matching row and column indices.
- There are $n$ pairs $(i,j)$ for the root cell such that $i=j$.  Once this is chosen, it belongs to $2^{n-1}$ submatrices with matching row and column indices.

Hence, in total there are $(n^2-n) \cdot 2^{n-2}+n \cdot 2^{n-1}=n(n+1)2^{n-2}$ rooted matrices with matching row and column indices.